# Symfony Error: "An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template"

Tags: php, symfony, twig, rendering, symfony4

I am trying to include

```
<link href="{{ asset('css/mystyle.css') }}"
      rel="stylesheet"/>
```

in my twig file and render it. But it gives me **Uncaught PHP Exception Twig_Error_Runtime:**

> "An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template
>   ("Asset manifest file "/../public/build/manifest.json" does not
>   exist.")

It does work when i use

```
link href="css/mystyle.css"
          rel="stylesheet"/>
```

.
Following is my controller:

```
    <?php

namespace App\Controller;

use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;

class WelcomeController extends AbstractController
{
    /**
     * @Route("/", name="welcome")
     */
    public function index()
    {
        return $this->render('welcome/index.html.twig');
    }
}
```

Following is my twig template:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">

    <title>Let's Explore Symfony 4</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet"
          href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.3/css/bootstrap.min.css"
          integrity="sha384-Zug+QiDoJOrZ5t4lssLdxGhVrurbmBWopoEl+M6BdEfwnCJZtKxi1KgxUyJq13dy"
          crossorigin="anonymous">

    <link href="{{ asset('css/mystyle.css') }}"
          rel="stylesheet"/>

</head>

<body>
<header>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-dark bg-dark">
        <div class="container">

            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Home</a>

            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
                <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Hello Page</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>

    </nav>
</header>

<main role="main" class="container main">
    <div>
        <h1>Let's Explore Symfony 4</h1>
        <p class="lead">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras rutrum sapien mauris, venenatis
            facilisis neque tincidunt vel. Maecenas vel felis vel turpis scelerisque eleifend. Fusce nec purus egestas,
            efficitur nisi ac, ultrices nulla. Pellentesque eu mollis tortor, in mollis nisl. Maecenas rhoncus quam non
            lacinia mollis.</p>
    </div>
</main>
</body>
</html>
```

How can i resolve this issue?

Comment: Did you execute bin/console asset:install before?

Comment: All solutions below did not solve my problem. Any other suggestions?

Comment: The answer from Sarath Kumar should help. As the error points out, the `manifest.json` doesn't exist. It can be automatically created once the assets are compiled. Eventually jsut the command `yarn encore dev` can resolve the problem.

Comment: You're assets are managed by webpack-encore so you'll just have to update your code. Remove the asset(...) method and expose it's content. Webpack should handle your assets for you. Update your code from this
`<link href="{{ asset('css/mystyle.css') }}"
      rel="stylesheet"/>`
to this
`<link href="{{ 'css/mystyle.css' }}"
      rel="stylesheet"/> `

Answer (score 36):

Execute the below commands:

```
yarn add --dev @symfony/webpack-encore

yarn add webpack-notifier --dev

yarn encore dev
```

It will generate the manifest.json file

Comment: This is the right answer. For me it was enough to run `yarn install` and `yarn encore dev` after installing the Webpack Encore with `composer`. The official [documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/current/frontend/encore/simple-example.html) is very good and contains everything.

Answer (score 17):

I have resolved this problem by not using json_manifest_path: ~

comment out the json_manifest_path by adding '#' in front of it
and add '~' after 'assets:'

```
framework:
    assets: ~
        #json_manifest_path: '%kernel.project_dir%/public/build/manifest.json'
```

Answer (score 4):

`yarn encore dev-server --hot` creates the manifest.json file

Answer (score 3):

manifest.json is new in Symfony 3.3.

So, you should have this lines in your config file :

> ```
> # app/config/config.yml
> framework:
>     # ...
>     assets:
>         json_manifest_path: '%kernel.root_dir%/../web/build/manifest.json'
> ```

If manifest.json isn't exists, you should create it, like this :

> {
>          "css/app.css": "build/css/mystyle.b916426ea1d10021f3f17ce8031f93c2.css",
>          "...": "..." 
>      }

Answer (score 2):

I have resolved this problem by not using `json_manifest_path: ~`

comment out the json_manifest_path by adding `#` in front of it and add `~` after `assets:`

```
framework:
    assets: ~
        #json_manifest_path: '%kernel.project_dir%/public/build/manifest.json'
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error and from the documentation, I did those two commands in the terminal:

```
npm install sass-loader@^12.0.0 sass --save-dev
npm run watch
```

(following the Webpack Encore required version, you can use `npm install sass-loader@^11.0.0` or lower version 10 or 9)

Answer (score 0):

Execute this command:

composer remove webpack

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Hello I had the same probleme and I've found this as a solution, you only have tu run this "composer require symfony/webpack-encore-bundle".
If it does not work try to run "npm build run" or "npm run watch", but before run it make sure that Node.js is installed as well as npm.

good luck

Answer (score -1):

Remember that the question is tagged **Symfony4**!

I have the same issue to add logo in navbar, favicon…

In Symfony4, there are no more *app* directory, so no *app/config/config.yml* !
In Symfony4, *web* directory doesn't exist anymore but there are new directory ***public***

As @Bijaya wrote, just specify *href* or *src* address in public

In my case, I have my logo: *myProjectName/public/logo_mom.png*

and in my controller, I have:

```
/**
 * @Route("/", name="home")
 */
public function home() {
    return $this->render('blog/home.html.twig', [
        'title' => "Bienvenue",
        'logo_path' => "logo_mom.png",
        'logo_alt' => "logo alt description",
    ]);
}
```

and in my *home.html.twig*:

```
{% block body %}
    <h1>{{ title }}</h1>
    <img src={{ logo_path }} alt={{ logo_alt}}>
```

and in my *template/base.html.twig*:

```
<link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico" />
```

So for me who discover Symfony4 without previous Symfony version knowledge, it is nice that doesn't required asset function or any other configuration!

Answer (score -1):

If removing `json_manifest_path` from `framework.yaml` did not help you, then just create a file in `public/build/manifest.json`. Put an empty json in the file: {}