# symfony admin bundle installation

Tags: php, symfony, webpack, symfony-sonata

I am learning the symfony sonata bundle, I installed the symfony skeleton project with `composer create-project symfony/website-skeleton sonata` command, and I enter into sonata directory and run `composer require sonata-project/admin-bundle` command as the guide on [symfonydoc](https://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/SonataAdminBundle/getting_started/installation.html#the-admin-interface), I checked all the configurations as the doc said, and the `cache:clear` and `assets:install` command all work fine, I started my server with `php bin/console server:start`, but when I visit the url 'http://localhost:8000/admin/dashboard' it reports error, `An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("Asset manifest file "/Users/kazuma/www/sonata/public/build/manifest.json" does not exist.").`

I made my project with symfony before, but I don't know much about the webpack, my asset directory is empty, when I run npm install it works fine too, I don't know what I've missed.

Comment: I opened my 'public' directory, I can only find bundles 'directory' and index.php file under it, under the 'bundles' directory there are 'sonataadmin' and 'sonatacore' directories, no 'build' directory or any 'manifest.json' file under 'public' directory

Comment: do any of the answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51393459/symfony-error-an-exception-has-been-thrown-during-the-rendering-of-a-template) help?

Comment: @Dragos, Yes, the first answer there works, I set the 'assets' option in 'assets.yaml' as '~', it works, thank you very much!

Comment: running `yarn install` should do these for you automatically.

Answer (score 0):

in Symfony 4

1. Create le the empty file rootProject/public/build/manifest.json
2. insert this code : [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UKmW0.png)

```html
{
    "bundles": {
        "Sonata\\AdminBundle\\SonataAdminBundle": ["all"]
    },
    "copy-from-recipe": {
        "config/": "%CONFIG_DIR%/",
        "src/": "%SRC_DIR%/"
    }
}
```