# An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("Asset manifest file "../manifest.json" does not exist.")

Tags: symfony4

I cloned a Symfony 4 web application (which work on the server) to a fresh installed VM, but after installing all the packages, I get this error message :

> An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template
>   ("Asset manifest file
>   "/var/www/html/kyc/htdocs/public/build/manifest.json" does not
>   exist.").

I tried this solution without success :

[Symfony Error: "An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51393459/symfony-error-an-exception-has-been-thrown-during-the-rendering-of-a-template)

Any idea ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You need to build your assets. Make sure you have encore installed, then run yarn encore dev.

Comment: Mmm, could you paste a screenshot of the error so I can see all the information? Besides, I said "yarn encore dev" but maybe you're not running on the "dev" environment, switch it to whatever env you're in and we will see :) gL!

Answer (score 0):

Change your asset.yaml file to

```
    framework:
        assets: ~
```

remove the cache and check again

Answer (score 0):

if you have something like this `<link href="{{ asset('css/mystyle.css') }}" rel="stylesheet"/>` then remove the asset() method and leave the contents exposed like this `<link href="{{ 'css/mystyle.css' }}" rel="stylesheet"/>`

I assume you're using webpack to manage your web assets